# An error occured while installing customizr theme on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

When I was installing the theme customizr I got this error. Now I am not able to login to my website. Whenever I login it gives following error:

URL of my website is www.nileshaswani.webuda.com you can check it out.

PHP Error Message

> Warning: require_once(/home/a6084419/public_html/wp-
>   content/themes/customizr/inc/init.php) [function.require-once]: failed
>   to open   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/a6084419/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/functions.php
>   on line 46

Second PHP Error Message:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   '/home/a6084419/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/init.php' 
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/a6084419/public_html/wp-content/themes/customizr/functions.php
>   on line 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong when you installed the theme, the reason depending on how the theme was being installed.

To back out of a theme install gone awry, access your site via FTP and browse to /wp-content/themes/customizr/.  Delete the folder.

You won't be able to access the front end of your site yet, but you will now be able to access the dashboard.  Log into your site and change the theme (or reinstall customizr).  Now you'll be able to access your site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems theme files got corrupted while theme installation. One approach would be tweaking from database. Use phpMyadmin from your cpanel. Find options table. Now edit two row in options table. One is `template` and another is `stylesheet`. Change it to default installed theme. Now you will be able to access admin panel `/wp-admin/`. Now try fresh installing your theme.

NOTE: While changing database it is recommended to keep a copy of backup.